# SQL Server local instance user login

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

I am working on an Azure Mobile Apps backend service, which I am trying to connect to a local SQL Server database, as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#howto-sqlexpress-setup). I have followed all the steps, except I am using SQL Server 2016 rather than 2014.

If I follow the Microsoft tutorial exactly, everything works fine. I am not sure what the environment variable is about, as I don't reference it anywhere, but anyway, when I run my app, I get the following output:

> Express server listening on port 3000
>   2016-06-19T09:37:39.331Z - error: Error occurred during table initialization ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'azuremobile'.  Reason: The password of the account must be changed.
>   at Connection. (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\backend\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:378:25)
>   at Connection.g (events.js:260:16)
>   at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>   at Connection.emit (events.js:169:7)
>   at Connection.processLogin7Response (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:672:16)
>   at Connection.message (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1082:21)
>   at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:519:45)
>   at MessageIO. (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:439:23)
>   at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>   at MessageIO.emit (events.js:166:7)

This seems to be because of the setting that is shown below, "User Must change password at next login"?

[image]

However, If I change the password, or delete and recreate the login but unchecking that feature. I get this:

> Error occurred during table initialization ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'azuremobile'.

I am possibly getting the password wrong, but I have tried this 6 times now. Is there a way I can check the password or anything else I can do to get my node project to login to my local SQL Server database?

**Update**:

Here is my UserMapping:

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure that the login you are creating has an appropriate user mapping for the database you're trying to connect to ?

Comment: @druzin How could I check that? In SQL Server Managment Studio, that login isn't mapped to any credentials?

Comment: What does it say on the User Mapping page of the user creation dialog ?

Comment: @druzin Sure, see the screenshot I have added to the question

Comment: @druzin Also, if I log into SQL Server Management Studio, with SQL Server Authentication (rather than the default Windows Auth), then the UserId and Password I use in my project are successful

Comment: What is the name of the database you are trying to connect to in your project though ( Initial catalog )

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I had a typo in the name of my database... There was nothing wrong with the credentials!